# How to display specific column for Loop & Merge in Qualtrics

Tags: qualtrics

I am using Qualtrics to make a survey.
What I want to do is the following:
Survey takers will provide their Subject ID in the first page.
This Subject ID will be referenced via Panel Data that I previously uploaded to Qualtrics.
I want to be able to use their ID to refer to a column in Loop & Merge.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Subject ID to reference panel data, respondents need to provide it in an Authenticator, not a survey question (the Authenticator will be the first page).

You can then pipe the Subject ID into a Loop & Merge field as:

```
${e://Field/Subject ID}
```